# How to test the reaction to a component event in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, tdd, svelte, svelte-testing-library

In Svelte, I have a parent component which listens to a [component event](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events) dispatched by a child component.

I know how to use `component.$on` to check that the dispatched event does the right thing *within the component which is dispatching*, [like so](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/component-testing-in-svelte#events).

But **I can't figure out how to check that the component which receives the dispatch does the right thing in response.**

Here's a basic example:

**Child.svelte**

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()
  
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    dispatch('results', 'some results')
  }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={ handleSubmit }>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Parent.svelte**

```
<script>
  import Child from './Child.svelte'

  let showResults = false

  function handleResults(event) {
    showResults = true
  }
</script>

<Child on:results={ handleResults } />

{ #if showResults }
  <p id='results'>Some results.</p>
{ /if }
```

The idea is to eventually write a test using `@testing-library/svelte` like:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte'
import Parent from './Parent.svelte'

test('shows results when it receives them', () => {
  const rendered = render(Parent)
 
  // ***
  // Simulate the `results` event from the child component?
  // ***

  // Check that the results appear.
})
```

If the parent were reacting to a DOM event, I would use [`fireEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/).

But I don't know how I would get a hold of the `<Child>` component in this case, and even if I could I'm guessing that Svelte is using a different mechanism for component events.

(Just to test it out, I used `createEvent` to fire a custom `results` event on one of the DOM elements rendered by `<Child>` but it didn't seem to do anything.)

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already planning on using `@testing-library/svelte`, I think the easiest way is not to try to manually trigger the `Child` component's `results` event, but to use Testing Library to grab the form/submit elements and trigger the submit event (using `fireEvent` a `SubmitEvent` on the `<form>` or their `@testing-library/user-event` library, or even a vanilla `dispatchEvent`). Svelte would then dispatch the custom `results` event that `Parent` is listening on.

Something like:

```
test('shows results when it receives them', async () => {
  // Arrange
  const rendered = render(Parent)

  const submitButton = rendered.getByRole('button', {
    name: /submit/i
  });

  const user = userEvent.setup();

  // Act
  await user.click(submitButton);

  // Assert
  const results = rendered.queryByText(/some results\./i);

  expect(results).not.toBe(null);
});
```

Hope this is what you had in mind.

---

**Edit**:
For mocking `Child.svelte`, something like this in a `__mocks__/Child.svelte` should work:

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    dispatch("results", "some results");
  }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

Which is the exact same implementation as the actual module (I gave the button a different label just to make it clear it's the mocked version when querying it), but the idea is that this would never need to change and is only used to dispatch a `results` event. Then you'd just need to tell Jest or whatever you're using that you're mocking it (`jest.mock("./Child.svelte");`), change the `getByRole` query to match the new name (or just leave the mock with the original name), then it should just work.

Whether you think that's worth it or not is up to you. I've generally had success testing the UI as a whole rather than mocking sub-components, but I guess it comes down to preference. Yes, you might have to change the test if the Child component changes, but only if you change the label of the button or change the user interaction mechanism.

You don't need to know about the details of the components, you don't even need to know that it's split into a separate Child component, all the test would care about is a general idea of the structure of the UI—that there's a button called "Submit" and that clicking on it should show an additional `<p>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @Desjardins! This makes sense and it does answer the question. With this approach, the Parent test has to know a lot about the Child component. I'm wondering if there's a way to mock out the Child component and/or simulate the dispatched event. Otherwise every time the Child component changes, this test would have to change too.

Comment: @jrh, that's true, you don't really get much of a traditional "unit" test with this approach. The idea behind this Testing Library is that, for UIs, it's testing that a user's interaction behaves as expected, which is why its primary functions are about grabbing things by their accessibility roles and performing user actions on them, without really caring about the name or details of the event. However, it should be possible to make a fake Child component that you can use to trigger the `results` event.